# Ошибка при верификации токена loader.io "URL exists, but token was not found "

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, loader

Ошибка при верификации токена, по инструкции сайт loader.io просит разместить токен по одному из представленных адресов, что я и сделал. Но при клике на кнопку верификация выскакивает ошибка "URL exists, but token was not found ". Сам токен точно находится по этому адресу и токен был вписан без ошибок. Может есть какие идеи в чем может быть причина ? В документации loader.io не нашел такой проблемы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Robots.txt стоит Allow для ботов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено путем написания в тех. поддержку и ручной верефикации токена с их стороны